# Configuration of the Interrupt Signal

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, interrupts, phy

I'm using this [IC- LAN9500A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN950x-Data-Sheet-DS00001875D.pdf) and want to know how to use pin 1, nPHY_INT.

I'm using internal PHY and want to generate output on this pin 1 (interrupt output)

Can someone tell me how to configure it? Is it a hardware configuration or software configuration?

It confuses a bit. In the above datasheet, looking at the pin description on page 20,
when using Internal PHY, it is mentioned as : **The internal PHY interrupt signal is
active-high.**

Whereas, in this [Hardware Checklist Document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LAN9500A%20QFN%20Rev%20A%20Schematic%20Checklist.pdf), page number 14, Misc point 3, it is mentioned as, when using the internal PHY, **the pin's signal would be active-low.**

Isnt it confusing? Can someone clarify both the questions on how to handle this pin?

Answer (score 0):

On page 20 you have the mention of both usages of the pin. Either an active high output or an active low input depending on the phy mode selected.

In your case you want to use the output, so you must configure the phy mode internal by setting the phy_sel pin to 0.

Comment: Any register settings to be updated when doing PHY_SEL to 0 ?